# php parameter with apostrophes

Tags: php, string, utf-8

I have string parameter with apostrophes that I need to pass it to another php page.
My code is:

```
echo '<form name="submitForm2" action="creatDocument.php?$formulation='.$formulation.'" method="POST">
         <input type="submit" value="pass"/>
         </form>';
```

The `$fomulation` parameter contain the string with hebrew characters that came from user.
if `$fomulation = אבג"דה`

`creatDocument.php` received just `$fomulation = אבג` .
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is that the URL parser is breaking on the single quotes. Check out the `URLEncode` method, to encode your query string parameters.

https://www.php.net/urlencode

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<form name="submitForm2" action="creatDocument.php?$formulation='.urlencode(utf8_encode($formulation)).'" method="POST">
     <input type="submit" value="pass"/>
     </form>';
```

Comment: It's work, but I have string with hebrew characters, and I not received any data now...

Comment: try an urldecode($_GET['$formulation']) in the  target page

Comment: Tried it, not received data with hebrew characters. If my parameters is `$formulation=אבג"דה`

Comment: OK i understand it look at the modification, add a utf8_encode into the urlencode

Comment: Do you mean to: `urlencode(utf8_encode($formulation))` ? it is not working too, I recieved something like this: ª× ××ª×××¢×, ××××;